# Curing autocorrelation when arma, arch do not help

Tags: time-series, arma, arch

I use monthly data to estimate relationship between some financial assets, get the following result using OLS with White covariance matrix (anticipating some sort of heteroskedactisity).

However, the AC/PACS analysis indicates strong autocorrelation and there seem to be volatility clustering on the residual chart:

[image]
[image]

The heteroskedasticity tests are all negative, trying to add any combination of ARMA terms or estimating ARCH/GARCH does not cure the problem of autocorrelation. It seems that there is some significant omitted variable in the error term that autocorrelates across time, but shouldn't the MA term fix this? 
P.S. unit root test on the dependent variable is also negative, so no need in differencing.

Any ideas what can be done?

Comment: What happened in 2014 and first half 2015?

Comment: I wish I knew. This data relates to US Treasury and STIR futures, as far as I remember nothing important happened during this period.